# Yootheme widgetkit video and image gallery?

Tags: image, video, gallery, slideshow

I am trying to find a way to play videos inside a yootheme widgetkit gallery.

Currently I am only able to show images, but i want to also have vimeo videos added to the slideshow...

Any thoughts please help.